# Can I fetch a local variable's value from a mocked function?

Tags: mockito

I have a function say `MyFunction(arg)` which I have mocked.

Inside the function, another function is called and the result of the second function is assigned to a local `variable(say myVar)` declared inside `MyFunction(arg)`.

Can I use mockito anyway to fetch the value of `myVar` in my test function?

Adding code :

OrderOperations.java

```
public OrderResponse createOrder(Orders order){

    OrderResponse orderResponse = new OrderResponse();
    ManipulatedOrder = partnerOrder;

    partnerOrder = parseXML(order) //This function manipulates the details of order object and gives back the result.

    String xmlRequest = xs.toXML(partnerOrder); //The response is converted to XML

    //Few modifications are done to the xmlRequest and then it is sent to another function

    orderResponse = invokeAPI(xmlRequest); //This function uses the xmlRequest.

    return orderResponse;
}
```

I want to test this function using JUNIT, mock this function and in someway want to capture what is being sent to invokeAPI if I pass test values to the Orders object.

Comment: Please share (a [mcve] of) your code instead of just describing it.

Comment: *Inside the function, another function is called*: no. Nothing is called in that function, since you mocked it.

Comment: @Mureinik Edited as per your suggestion.

Comment: To add to it, I'm trying to use verify() function of mockito but not sure if I have understood its usage well. 
ArgumentCaptor<OrderOperations>ArgCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(OrderOperations.class);

 Mockito.verify(orderItems).createOrder(inputOrder).CCDArgCaptor.capture(); 
No matter what I do, I am getting errors. orderItems is the mock object of the class created as: OrderOperations orderItems = Mockito.spy(OrderOperations.class);